# A word to describe a person that everything come to them late in life!

Tags: expressions, terminology, epithet-requests, diction

Many years ago I came across a word and when I looked it up it was described as:

A person everything comes to, late in life!

Answer (score 6):

That's the very definition of a [*late bloomer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TpQ3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT112&lpg=PT112&dq=idioms%20late%20bloomer&source=bl&ots=ED_ml3A-yQ&sig=xwHPpUfxZRisaa5NNNWyDoegoxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiz7id7djYAhUCy2MKHUh9CWsQ6AEIXTAJ#v=onepage&q=idioms%20late%20bloomer&f=false):

> When someone does not obtain success with their interests, talents, or
>   personality until later in their lives, we say they are a late
>   bloomer.